# Bash scripting: detect first day of month

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, date

I wrote three bash files:

1. `incremental_backup`
2. `full_backup`
3. `execution`

Now I want another bash script do the following :

```
if (date is the start of month 1/-/----)
then     
    invoke `full_back_up`
else
    invoke `incremental_backup`
```

How can I write this script?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't do this. Instead use two separate cron jobs to invoke your tasks.

```
15 5 1 * * scripts/full_back_up
15 5 2-31 * * scripts/incremental_backup
```

Comment: I do this to mark backups as "yearly", "monthly", "daily" in file name and then I delete with `find` command. Is this wrong for some reason?

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
if [ `date +%d` != "01" ] 
then
    incremental_backup
else
    full_backup
fi
```

Comment: Your answer's the same as mine, and earlier, so I deleted mine.  You might want to de-capitalise the "I" in your fisrt "if", though!

Comment: You should leave your answer up. There are quite a lot of duplicate answers on the site. It all adds to the community.